# biblatex: linking entries with one biber run

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I'm currently tring to link two different entries, a text and its translation, so that they are output together. The entry of the translation is given in the field "usera". If more code is needed, let me know, for the moment I'll just give an abstract explanation.

So we have `@inbook{original, … usera = {translation}} and @inbook{translation, …}`.

Which gives something like:

> Author: Title, location year [translated as: Title, location year].

In the bibliography I do the output of the translation with a modified version of `\fullcite`. This is probably a brutal solution, but it works.

Except for two problems:

- Currently I need two runs of LaTeX and biber. Since the `\fullcite` is only called when the bibliography is written, the system doesn't know of the entry `translation` in the first run. I tried all kind of ways to hand the content of `usera` over to `biblatex` in the first run, but I failed.
- Once LaTeX and biber have run twice, I get two entries for translation – one as a part of the bibliography entry of original, and then a separate one for original itself. I know that I could filter this by using categories in the document, but I'd like to come up with a solution where translation isn't printed by default

Comment: There are no really good solutions to this sort of "related entries" issue. It's something which will be fixed in biblatex 2.x/biber 1.0 which will have a general mechanism for doing this sort of thing. It's already implemented in biber but the biblatex interface and default style changes are yet to be done though as it's quite a lot of work.

Comment: Well, I thought I could take a shortcut. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `\fullcite` for the translator is issued at `\finentry`? Under this approach, I suspect the only way you could hope to obtain single-run solution is to invoke `\nocite{*}` within the document body and filter `\printbibliography` (using a `filter`, `category` or the field: `options = {skipbib=true}`).

A single-run, filter-free alternative could be obtained using an `entryset`. However if the translated entry is your actual source, I'd sooner cite it directly and make use of the `translator` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{translatedas}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  translatedas = {translated as}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{1}
       {}
       {\setunit{}%
        \bibopenbracket%
        \bibsentence\bibstring{translatedas}\addcolon\space}}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{1}
       {\adddotspace}
       {\setunit{}%
        \adddot\bibclosebracket}}%
  \let\finentrypunct=\empty%
  \finentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Set{orig:trans,
  entryset = {orig,trans}}
@Book{orig,
  author = {Original Author},
  title = {Original Title},
  publisher = {Original Publisher},
  location = {Original Location},
  year = {1986}}
@Book{trans,
  author = {Translator},
  title = {Translated Title},
  publisher = {Translated Publisher},
  location = {Translated Location},
  year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{orig:trans}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that confirms about what I was thinking. As Phil wrote it doesn't really seem to work (yet) the way I'd like.

Comment: @Simifilm True. But you have reasonable workarounds to use in the meantime. BTW: `\entrydata{\thefield{usera}}{<code>}` is a neat alternative if you find `\fullcite` clumsy.